# Que signifie « on continue » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

In my textbook, a girl seems to say goodbye by saying “On continue?”, to which her friend replies "Bien sûr!". What does this mean?

---

Dans mon livre de cours, un fille semble dire *au revoir* avec l’expression « On continue? » Que signifie cette formulation?

Comment: I have never seen "On continue?" in this context; maybe you could add a bit more of the text so we have a better idea of the contex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems unlikely that the girl from your textbook want to express *goodbye* by saying “On continue ?”. Literally, it means « Shall we continue? » although in a quite familiar way.

---

Il est peu probable la demoiselle en question veuille signifier *au revoir* par les mots « On continue ? » L’expression signifie littéralement « Shall we continue? » dans un registre plutôt familier.

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure it was a goodbye, but it was just at the end of the conversation, so I assumed there would be some sort of a goodbye. Reading your answer, though, I see how "On continue?" in the meaning "Shall we continue?" fits. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to mean "goodbye" by saying "on continue?".

The English equivalent would be "**to be continued?**"

Comment: Definitely not true in Europe (France, Switzerland, Belgium), maybe in North America?

Comment: In this context, I would translate “To be continued?” by “*On continue la prochaine fois ?*”. And I wouldn’t consider it a proper goodbye.

Comment: @Annoyed It is also not used in North America as a good bye.